# how to resolve this error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot delete property '0' of [object Array]"

Tags: angular, rxjs, action, ngrx, reducers

```
on(deleteAnswerAction, (s, { answerId }) => {
    const findAnswerIndex = s.findIndex((item) => item.id === answerId);
    return s.splice(findAnswerIndex, 1);
  }),
```

this is my reducer on dispatching action deleteAnswer it should delete the answer with respective answerId.

Comment: Can you tell what data is there in s

Comment: in s i have answerId and title

Answer (score 6):

Because of use state manager the main paradigm here: `immutability`. You can't mutate your state, you can set a new state only. `Splice` changes the original data source.

Solution:

```
...
  const newState = [...s].splice(findAnswerIndex, 1);

  return newState;
}),
```

Comment: Actually i tried this "[...s]" and its working but in findAnswerIndex even we are getting -1 then also answer is getting deleted which is next element in array of object